# which UITableViewCellStyle can use to make uitableview 's style similar to standard iPhone messages

Tags: ios4

I am trying to build layout of the uitableview  (List ) similar to 
standard iphone message list . Meaning margin from left hand side and bold black label to display name of msg sender or reciever .Then below tha text with gray color showing atleast two lines of text then on right hand side date with blue color text.

How can i achieve this .I just want to Know the UITableViewCellStyle for such type of layout

If any one has some solution for this please do write to this thread

Kind Regards

Paggyyy123

Answer (score 1):

I would use the plain style. Here is a [link](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) how you can make a totally custom table view. This should suite all your needs.